# Azure DevOps Server (on-prem) how to change access URL?

Tags: azure-devops-server-2020

I have an Azure DevOps Server (on-prem 2020) that I currently access using the URL format in the form of:

```
*http://myserver:8080/tfs/...*
```

and would like to switch over to using a URL in the form of

```
*http://abcservice.myorg.com/tfs/...*`
```

I've created the A Record but cannot find appropriate documentation on how to apply it.

I'm just wondering if it is just a matter of adding an appropriate binding to the web site and reporting server, then updating the admin tool, or are there more steps involved?

Comment: Did you look at the documentation?

Comment: yes, my question was based on having done this.  I am wondering if there are other steps that need to be done (or more likely, any gotchas that one needs to be aware of).